# WPF Chart binding error

Tags: wpf, binding, charts

i have problem to correctly bind data to WPF Chart. When i'm setting ItemsSource i get error:

> *Assigned dependent axis cannot be used.  The data may not be able to be rendered on the provided axis or the series may require that they axis has an origin.*

```
oc = new ObservableCollection<Pair>();
heartBeats.ItemsSource = oc;
```

to Pair i'm saving int and long

XAML:

```
...
xmlns:charting="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit" >
<charting:Chart x:Name="ApplicatioChart">
            <charting:Chart.Series>
                <charting:ColumnSeries x:Name="heartBeats" Title="Working Set" 
                 DependentValueBinding="{Binding First}" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Second}" >

                    <charting:ColumnSeries.IndependentAxis>
                        <charting:CategoryAxis Orientation="X" />
                    </charting:ColumnSeries.IndependentAxis>                    
                    <charting:ColumnSeries.DependentRangeAxis>
                        <charting:LinearAxis  Orientation="Y"  />
                    </charting:ColumnSeries.DependentRangeAxis>

                </charting:ColumnSeries>
            </charting:Chart.Series>
        </charting:Chart>
```

Please help.. :(

Comment: You seem to binding both the Dependent and Independent values to "First"??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i resolved it this way:

```
<charting:Chart Title="Engine Performance" x:Name="ApplicationChart">
    <!-- Power curve -->
    <charting:LineSeries x:Name="heartBeats" 
                    Title="ManagedHeapSize"       
                    IndependentValueBinding="{Binding EventTime}"
                    DependentValueBinding="{Binding ManagedHeapSize}">

        <!-- Vertical axis -->
        <charting:LineSeries.DependentRangeAxis>
            <charting:LinearAxis
                            Orientation="Y"
                            Title="ManagedHeapSize"                                   
                            Interval="10000000" Focusable="True"
                            ShowGridLines="True"/>
        </charting:LineSeries.DependentRangeAxis>
    </charting:LineSeries>                      

    <charting:Chart.Axes>
        <!-- Shared horizontal axis -->
        <charting:LinearAxis
                        Orientation="X"
                        Title="EventTime"
                        Interval="100"
                        ShowGridLines="True"/>
    </charting:Chart.Axes>
</charting:Chart>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't see anything wrong with the mark up (apart from the same Property being bound as both the dependent and independent value).

It seems to work fine in the Silverlight version, I don't have the WPF version to play with.

Try removing the definition for the DependentRangeAxis, to see whether it works with the default one.